# App crashing from ipa file but run from xcode

Tags: crash, ipa

My app is crashing from ipa file. This is my console log. I am using firebase in this project? I can not figure out the problem. Is it arising for firebase or other causes?

```
Version:             3.5 (3.5)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]


Date/Time:           2018-05-07 14:00:50.9291 +0600
Launch Time:         2018-05-07 14:00:50.7374 +0600
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.1 (15C153)
Baseband Version:    4.30.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1823be364 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x181604528 objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1823be2ac +[NSException raise:format:] + 115
3   Photo                           0x1049f62e0 _h`enter code here`idden#57437_ + 171
4   Photo                           0x1049f60a4 _hidden#57435_ + 383
5   Photo                           0x1049f5e44 _hidden#57433_ + 359
6   CoreFoundation                  0x18235033c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 19
7   CoreFoundation                  0x18234f8dc _CFXRegistrationPost + 419
8   CoreFoundation                  0x18234f640 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 59
9   CoreFoundation                  0x1823cd024 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1407
10  CoreFoundation                  0x182285f60 _CFXNotificationPost + 379
11  Foundation                      0x182cb3348 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 67
12  Photo                           0x104973d30 _hidden#53366_ + 387
13  Photo                           0x104972bdc _hidden#53351_ + 287
14  Photo                           0x104972a10 _hidden#53349_ + 391
15  Photo                           0x1047056e8 _hidden#31344_ + 3348200 (__hidden#31777_:205)
16  UIKit                           0x18b90e37c -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 383
17  UIKit                           0x18baffc58 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3435
18  UIKit                           0x18bb04aa8 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1711
19  UIKit                           0x18bda02d4 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 799
20  UIKit                           0x18c07812c +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 159
21  UIKit                           0x18bd9ff38 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 251
22  UIKit                           0x18bda0798 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 731
23  UIKit                           0x18c5257d0 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 259
```

How to solve this problem. Please help.

Comment: Have you figured it out? Having the same issue here